# Enabling and Disabling JCheckBox's depending on JComboBox.SelectedItem

Tags: java, swing, awt

OK so I have a Panel containing 12 JCheckBox's, Upon the interface loading all of the JCheckBox's are disabled. When a user selects an option from the JComboBox I want only certain JCheckBox's to be enabled depending on the item selected in the JComboBox.

At the moment in the JComboBoxActionPerformed i am enabling all of the JCheckBoxes relevant to the selection but prior to doing so attempting to disable all buttons that are currently enabled (In case the selected item in the JComboBox is changed).

The code i have to disable any enabled buttons is as follows:

```
public void disableBoxes() {
    for (JCheckBox j : ArrayOfJCheckBox) {
        if (j.isEnabled()) {
            j.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This does not however do anything, If I remove the call for this method from the
JComboBoxActionPerformed method then the JCheckBox's enable as i would expect. Leading me to assume that the problem lies with this code.

Furthermore i am currently creating the `ArrayOfJCheckBox` manually, i was wondering if there is a way i could do it by maybe adding getting all of the JCheckBox's inside the panel and adding them to a list? If this is possible would it then be possible to iterate through the list like i am already attempting to do?

Thanks for any help!

Dean

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Hi, sorry I haven't been able to get on the computer much, other things came up, I appreciate that I may not have provided enough information and apologise for that, I understand the concept in your answer below but I do not fully understand it, this has made me decide to take a closer look at the swing and awt libraries, at the minute I have been using netbeans to create all of my GUI'S, Thanks for all your help and the time you put into answering my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state:

> OK so I have a Panel containing 12 JCheckBox's, Upon the interface loading all of the JCheckBox's are disabled. When a user selects an option from the JComboBox I want only certain JCheckBox's to be enabled depending on the item selected in the JComboBox.

We don't know what criteria you would use to decide which JCheckBox would be enabled or disabled, but that's not super critical for the moment.

> At the moment in the JComboBoxActionPerformed i am enabling all of the JCheckBoxes relevant to the selection but prior to doing so attempting to disable all buttons that are currently enabled (In case the selected item in the JComboBox is changed).

This should work.

> The code i have to disable any enabled buttons is as follows:
>
> ```
> public void disableBoxes() {
>     for (JCheckBox j : ArrayOfJCheckBox) {
>         if (j.isEnabled()) {
>             j.setEnabled(false);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This does not however do anything, If I remove the call for this method from the JComboBoxActionPerformed method then the JCheckBox's enable as i would expect. Leading me to assume that the problem lies with this code.

This should work, but your post doesn't show us why it would not work, and so given the information presented we can't help solve the specific reason for just why it not working yet.

> Furthermore i am currently creating the ArrayOfJCheckBox manually, i was wondering if there is a way i could do it by maybe adding getting all of the JCheckBox's inside the panel and adding them to a list? If this is possible would it

Can't help well since we don't know how you are creating the "ArrayOfJCheckBox manually" yet as you've posted no code, nor can we help with the second request since we have no idea of how your program is structured.

---

Having said all this, it should be easy to create a List of JCheckBox or JToggleButton (the parent class) and then iterate through the list enabling and disabling components as the need arises.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CheckBoxList extends JPanel {
   private static final int CHECK_BOX_COUNT = 12; // number of JCheckBoxes
   private List<JCheckBox> checkBoxList = new ArrayList<>(); // list of JCheckBoxes
   private DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer> cModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(); // combo box model
   private JComboBox<Integer> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(cModel); 

   public CheckBoxList() {
      // create JPanel to hold JCheckBoxes
      JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 5));
      // create JCheckBoxes and add to both the above JPanel and the checkBoxList 
      for (int i = 0; i < CHECK_BOX_COUNT; i++) {
         String text = "CheckBox " + i;
         JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(text);
         checkBox.setEnabled(false);  // disabled by default
         checkBoxPanel.add(checkBox);
         checkBoxList.add(checkBox);
      }

      // fill our combo box's model. For this example, I'm just going to use
      // Integers, and then enable only the JCheckBoxes that are multiples of the selected int
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         cModel.addElement(i + 1);
      }
      
      comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1); // set combo at empty
      comboBox.addActionListener(new ComboListener()); // add ActionListner
      
      // JPanel to hold the JComboBox
      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      centerPanel.add(comboBox);
      int gap = 35;
      centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));

      // add all to the main JPanel (this)
      gap = 5;
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(checkBoxPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
   }
   
   private class ComboListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // get combo's selection
         int selection = (Integer) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
         
         // use the information to enable/disable JCheckBoxes
         for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxList.size(); i++) {
            if (i % selection == 0) {
               checkBoxList.get(i).setEnabled(true);
            } else {
               checkBoxList.get(i).setEnabled(false);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   // create and display GUI
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      CheckBoxList mainPanel = new CheckBoxList();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBoxList");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Again, if this doesn't help, then You are best served by creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, similar to my code above.